# Java HTMLUnit MalformedURLException

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute this code from the [HTMLUnit tutorial](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html):

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

but I get the MalformedURLException in the second line when saving it in Eclipse (if I compile and run the code, I get it too). What's the problem? TIA

PS: I'm new to Java

**Up:**

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/CredentialsProvider
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in Eclipse 3.5 and it is working correctly, and the test is passing.  I assume that you have included the necessary HTMLUnit JARs into your project?  I took all the JARs from the HTMLUnit `lib` directory and added them to the build path of my project.

Also, can you catch the exception and post the stack trace here?

```
try {
  final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
  assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.project.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;



public class Practice1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            HtmlPage page;
            try {
                page =  (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
                 System.out.println("Title="+ page.getTitleText());
            } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your stacktrace you have

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider
```

this isn't a malformed URL exception.

As [confirmed by JARFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider), org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider class should come from commons-httpclient-3.*.jar. Thus the cause of the problem must be that you don't have Commons HTTPClient 3.x JARs in your classpath.